# How to concat number to a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a calculator with HTML, CSS, and JS. Currently, I want a number to be concatenated to the output everytime I click a number button. Does anyone know how to do this because my code isn't working. The console keeps returning `output.concat is not a function`

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");

numbers.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener("click", () => {
        output.concat(number);
    })
})
```

```html
<div>
    <div data-output></div>
    <button data-clear>C</button>
    <button data-operator>/</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operator>*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operator>-</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operator>+</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-equals>=</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: How have you defined `output`? If you *did* define it, did you mean `output.textContent += number`? NB: you have a square bracket missing in the first line.

Comment: No, I didn't define it. Could you tell me how to do that? Do i just set it equal to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `output`, as currently it is undefined. Do it like this:

```
const output = document.querySelector("[data-output]");
```

And then, you must treat it like an element, not like a string. The same is true for the `number` variable: it is not a string (nor number), but a button element. So read and add content using the `textContent` property on both involved elements:

```
output.textContent += number.textContent;
```

NB: You have an error in your first line. It needs a closing `]` in the selector:

```
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
```

Code:

```js
const output = document.querySelector("[data-output]");
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");

numbers.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener("click", () => {
        output.textContent += number.textContent;
    })
})
```

```html
<div>
    <div data-output></div>
    <button data-clear>C</button>
    <button data-operator>/</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operator>*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operator>-</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operator>+</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-equals>=</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Okay, I did that. However, when I click on a number, it doesn't actually display the number, it only displays `[object HTMLButtonElement]`

Comment: I had already updated my answer to tackle that other issue in your code: `number` is a button element, not a string/number.

Comment: Next thing you need to do, is to make the operator buttons work...

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot to scroll down lol. Yep, let's hope I get it!

Answer (score 0):

I probably won't take this approach but building on your code you probably want something like

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operator = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operator]");
const clear = document.getElementById("clear");

const output = document.getElementById("output");
resu=""
numbers.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener("click", () => {
         resu+=number.textContent
      output.textContent=resu
    })
})
 operator.forEach(op => {
    op.addEventListener("click", () => {
     if(output.textContent.charAt(output.textContent.length-1)===op.textContent) return
     else {resu+=op.textContent
  output.textContent=resu}
    })
})
clear.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  output.textContent=""
})
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-output></div>
  <button data-clear id="clear">C</button>
  <button data-operator>/</button>
  <button data-number>7</button>
  <button data-number>8</button>
  <button data-number>9</button>
  <button data-operator>*</button>
  <button data-number>4</button>
  <button data-number>5</button>
  <button data-number>6</button>
  <button data-operator>-</button>
  <button data-number>1</button>
  <button data-number>2</button>
  <button data-number>3</button>
  <button data-operator>+</button>
  <button data-number>0</button>
  <button data-number>.</button>
  <button data-equals>=</button>
</div>
<div id="output">#######</div>
```